# Convert YAML multi-line values to folded block scalar style?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Using [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/) I tried to get a YAML in a certain style, more specifically one where single-line strings start at same line as `:` and multi-line strings using a folded scalar style (`|`/`|-`) and lines being limited to a certain amount of characters (word-wrapped).

My attempt so far heavily influenced by a [similar function called `walk_tree` in the sources](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/00c7352d22d00307ffa233b21d8a01a6ed6db4d0/scalarstring.py?fileviewer=file-view-default):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ruamel.yaml

from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import ScalarString, PreservedScalarString

def walk_tree(base):
    from ruamel.yaml.compat import string_types

    if isinstance(base, dict):
        for k in base:
            v = base[k]
            if isinstance(v, string_types):
                v = v.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n').strip()
                base[k] = ScalarString(v) if '\n' in v else v
            else:
                walk_tree(v)
    elif isinstance(base, list):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(base):
            if isinstance(elem, string_types) and '\n' in elem:
                print(elem) # @Anthon: this print is in the original code as well
                base[idx] = preserve_literal(elem)
            else:
                walk_tree(elem)

with open("input.yaml", "r") as fi:
    inp = fi.read()

loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader
data = ruamel.yaml.load(inp, loader)

walk_tree(data)

dumper = ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper

with open("output.yaml", "w") as fo:
    ruamel.yaml.dump(data, fo, Dumper=dumper, allow_unicode=True)
```

But then I get an exception: `ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: …`. I get no exception if I replace `ScalarString` with `PreservedScalarString` as is the case in the original `walk_tree` code but then I get the literal blocks again which is not what I want.

So how can my code be fixed so that it will work?

Comment: The call to `print` will be gone in 0.13.8, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If my answer doesn't do what you need, please include a sample input (and output if that is different) YAML file, by editing it into your question. You should not put in *EDIT* if you do. Leave a short comment, that will trigger a notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `ScalarString` is a base class for `LiteralScalarString`, it has no representer as you found out. You should just make/keep  this a Python string, as that deals with special characters appropriately (quoting strings that need to be quoted to conform to the YAML specification).

Assuming you have input like this:

```
- 1
- abc: |
    this is a short string scalar with a newline
    in it
- "there are also a multiline\nsequence element\nin this file\nand it is longer"
```

You probably want to do something like:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import LiteralScalarString, preserve_literal


def walk_tree(base):
    from ruamel.yaml.compat import string_types

    def test_wrap(v):
        v = v.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n').strip()
        return v if len(v) < 72 else preserve_literal(v)

    if isinstance(base, dict):
        for k in base:
            v = base[k]
            if isinstance(v, string_types) and '\n' in v:
                base[k] = test_wrap(v)
            else:
                walk_tree(v)
    elif isinstance(base, list):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(base):
            if isinstance(elem, string_types) and '\n' in elem:
                base[idx] = test_wrap(elem)
            else:
                walk_tree(elem)

yaml = YAML()

with open("input.yaml", "r") as fi:
    data = yaml.load(fi)

walk_tree(data)

with open("output.yaml", "w") as fo:
    yaml.dump(data, fo)
```

to get output:

```
- 1
- abc: "this is a short string scalar with a newline\nin it"
- |-
  there are also a multiline
  sequence element
  in this file
  and it is longer
```

Some notes:

- Use of `LiteralScalarString` is preferred over `PreservedScalarString`. The latter name a remnant from the time it was the only preserved string type.
- you probably had no sequence elements that where strings, as you did not import `preserve_literal`, although it was still used in the copied code.
- I factored out the "wrapping" code into test_wrap, used by both value and element wrapping, the max line length for that was set at 72 characters.
- the value `data[1]['abc']` loads as `LiteralScalarString`. If you want to preserve existing literal style string scalars, you should test for those before testing on type `string_types`.
- I used the new API with an instance of `YAML()`
- You might have to  set the `width` attribute to something like 1000, to prevent automatic line wrapping, if you increase 72 in the example to above the default of 80. (`yaml.width = 1000`)